# How can I make the LightDM lock screen my gnome-shell lock screen in 12.04

Tags: gnome, 12.04, lightdm, lock-screen

In Unity, LightDM is the default lock screen. Is it possible to make LightDM my default lock screen in gnome-shell ?

Comment: Are you sure? The lock screen in 12.04 is still gnome-screensaver as far as I can tell.

Comment: I guess you want to have the same lock screen for both gnome-shell and unity.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!